# How do i get back (display) the elevation points on the alert pop up.

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get back the elevation values from the code on the alert pop up like i am able to get the values of lat and lng. i am trying to get the three values (lat, lng and elevation heights) in an array so that i can later display the values using OpenGL but i am stuck on this part only as everything is working fine. This is the code i am using.  thanks

```
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var nw = new google.maps.LatLng (ne.lat(), sw.lng());
  var se = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng());

  for(var i = 0 ; i<= (ne.lat() - sw.lat()); i+=0.01)
 { for(var j =0 ; j<=(ne.lng() - sw.lng());j+=0.01)
      {
       var tmpele; //temp variable for elevation<br/>
       lt.push(sw.lat()+i);<br/>
       ln.push(sw.lng()+ j);<br/>

       var d = new google.maps.LatLng((sw.lat()+i),(sw.lng()+ j));
               loca.push(d);
       el.push(pospoint(loca));
      } }
      alert(lt);
      alert(ln);

      alert(el);

   }
   function disp()
   {
   alert(el);
   }
   function pospoint(loca)
   {

    var tmp;
    var positionalRequest = {    
                'locations': loca   
                           }
       elevationService.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) { 
           if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                    tmp=results;
                //  alert('got:'+tmp);
                //  return tmp;
                    }
                     });
    return tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [elevation service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) is asynchronous.  You can't return anything from it, you can only *use* the data (when it is available) in the callback function.

Comment: thanks.. i also want to know if then i need to draw all these values using OpenGL over a sphere, then how i would be able to collect the elevation data into the array with the lat and lng.

Comment: As described in the documentation referenced, the elevation service is subject to a quota and rate limits.  It will return "sampled elevation data along paths, allowing you to calculate the equidistant elevation changes along routes", or you can request the specific points individually (as long as you respect the service limits).